# Python Subprocess SSH closes connection

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that uses the subprocess module to connect to a server via SSH.

```
# python 3

def foo():
    menu = ["1 = one.com",
        "2 = two.com",
        "3 = three.com"
        ]
    for item in menu:
        print(item)

    choice = input("Which host?: ")

    if choice == "1":
        user = "users-name"
        host = "one.com"
        port = "22"
        subprocess.Popen(['ssh', user + '@' + host, '-p', port])
   elif
    ...
    ...


foo()
```

When I run the script, it connects to the server but then terminates the connection after I press any key. It just kind of, drops the connection silently and goes back to typing on localhost.

Is subprocess not meant to handle a concurrent connection? I am merely asking it to connect and do nothing else. Advice, tips, suggestions?

Comment: You probably need to use the '-t' option for SSH, and call Popen with `stdin=sys.stdin` to connect your terminal to the ssh session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be multiple answers to this, but assuming your command line, configuration and credentials are all correct and the `ssh` call on its own would succeed, the problem is (also a assuming a bit what happens in your code, or if the above example is more or less complete) following:

You fork and execute ssh (that's what `Popen` did), but your parent process (script) continues to run and eventually finishes, and when it does, it also clobbers the child it started, hence dropping you back to your hosts console even though you might have seen the other machine's prompt.

If I understands your intention correctly, you can do the following:

```
child = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', user + '@' + host, '-p', port])
child.wait()
```

Or just use a different method of starting your `ssh` such as `check_call()` that will hand control over to the child process and wait until its done..

Hope this helps.

---

Now when I see the above snippet, I cannot resits to give some unsolicited style advice/hints that can hopefully make your life a bit easier. I would just have a list of choices:

```
choices = [("one.com", "one_com_user", "one_com_port"), ...]
```

And generate the menu entries out of that... based on your input (converted to `int`, e.g. as `entered`), you could use `choices[entered]` to call `ssh` as wanted with corresponding arguments in the list and handle `IndexError` / out of range values with whatever response you wanted to do in case user specified unknown value.

That would make your code more concise (no conditional clauses), as well as easier to read and maintain (all hosts information in one place).

---

And one more regarding `ssh`call. You can skip concatenating strings and stick to list of arguments as you otherwise already do. `..., user + '@' + host, ...` and `..., '-l', user, host, ...`. Should work with (hopefully) most `ssh` clients.

Comment: Thank you so much! Using this to follow up on my research has been hugely beneficial to me.